# MongoDB CL: How can I escape "(" in regex literals?

Tags: mongodb

## Problem

Using the `mongo` command-line tool, I want to fetch documents containing " (" in a string field using a regex literal, like this:

```
{writers: / \(/}
```

However this fails in the `mongo` command line tool (v4.4.0), presumably because it's looking for a closing parentheses `)` despite `(` being escaped:

[image]

## What I've tried

Double escaping `/ \\(/` also does not work:

[image]

## Workarounds

1. The expression works fine in Compass:

[image]

2. I can express `(` using its octal escape sequence `{writers: / \50/}`:

[image]

3. I can use `{regex...}` with a *string* literal:

[image]

### Version

I'm using `mongo 4.2.9` and `4.4.0`:

[image]

Is there a way to match "(" characters in regex literals without resorting such workarounds?

`/.../` is a much cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In the `mongo` shell, unfortunately I don't think there's a cleaner way other than doing `\\(`. This is the limitation of the `mongo` shell itself.

However, it is possible to use the new [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install) (currently beta) to do what you want:

```
❯ mongosh
Current sessionID:  71d48f548f666555d896a975
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Using MongoDB: 4.4.0
Using Mongosh Beta: 0.0.5

For more information about mongosh, please see the wiki: github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh/wiki

> db.test.find({val: /\(/})
[ { _id: 5f5886ab588163bae7b4e1b5, val: '()' } ]
```

Note that the backslash escape is still required, since the bracket is part of PCRE syntax.

Comment: `db.movies.find({writers: / \\(/})` does not work either.  It produces the same result as `/ \(/`; a continuation prompt (`...`)

Comment: No you'd have to do `db.test.find({val: {$regex: '\\('}})`. This is an issue with the js interpreter in the mongo shell as I alluded to in the answer. This is partly why mongosh was created I think